# Passing a function through a linked list of objects

Tags: python, function, object, linked-list

I have a class that creates a multiply linked list.  Each node can have several (or one or no) children.  The node has a pointer to its latest child node, and each child node has a pointer to it previous sibling.  So I can walk the entire tree by taking each latest child, and then each of its siblings, in turn.  This function walks the three successfully, but doesn't do anything useful:

```
def walk_the_tree(self):
    if not self.latestChild is None:
        self.latestChild.walk_the_tree()
    if not self.sib is None:
        self.sib.walk_the_tree()
```

Now, what I really want to do is to pass some kind of argument so that a member function can be executed at each node.  Here's something that won't compile, but I hope it gets as what I am wanting:

```
def walk_the_tree(self, fcn):
    self.fcn()
    if not self.latestChild is None:
        self.latestChild.walk_the_tree()
    if not self.sib is None:
        self.sib.walk_the_tree()
```

So, fcn could be, for instance, just the class `__repr__`, so I can get all info on all the nodes quickly.  Or it might be `create_new_child()` which would determine whether the node needs a new child and, if so, create it.  I would like the user to be able to pick this without relying on some kind of flag.  For instance, what I *don't want* is something like:

```
def walk_the_tree(self, fcnflg):
    if (fcnflg == 1): self.__repr__()
    if (fcnflg == 2): self.create_new_child()
    if not self.latestChild is None:
        self.latestChild.walk_the_tree()
    if not self.sib is None:
        self.sib.walk_the_tree()
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Functions are first-class objects. So it should just work. Don't do `self.fnc` because that won't be defined.

Comment: It definitely smells as an OOP practice, but `obj.walk_the_tree(obj.create_new_child)` is what you are looking for

Comment: Yeah, I would just make it a module-level function. `def walk_tree(tree, f)`. I'm pretty radical about keeping classes succinct, though, and this could definitely be a method.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Would very much appreciate an example if it's not too much trouble.  Thanks.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I've added an example using a method. The class just wraps a list, but it should get the point across.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Much obliged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `self.fcn` but that isn't defined. Just use `fcn`. Here is a contrived example:

```
>>> class MyContainer(object):
...     def __init__(self, iterable=None):
...         if iterable is not None:
...             self.data = list(iterable)
...         else:
...             self.data = []
...     def walk_container(self, f):
...         for x in self.data:
...             print(f(x))
...     def _increment(self, x):
...         return x + 1
...     def print_increments(self):
...         self.walk_container(self._increment)
...
>>> c = MyContainer([0,1,2])
>>> c.print_increments()
1
2
3
>>>
```

Or if you want, use non-methods externally:

```
>>> c.walk_container(lambda x: x**2)
0
1
4
>>>
```